# javascript date.utc problem

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

I'm trying to compare 2 dates using javascript. 1 at the end of the month and 1 at the beginning. I need to compare these 2 dates in seconds so I'm using the Date.UTC javascript function.

Here's the code:

```
var d = Date.UTC(2010,5,31,23,59,59);
document.write(d);

var d2 = Date.UTC(2010,6,1,12,20,11);
document.write(d2);
```

The output for is:

```
1278028799000
1277986811000
```

This is telling me that **1/6/2010** is less than **5/31/2010** in milliseconds.

How is that possible? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `month` parameter to `Date.UTC()` is 0-indexed; January is 0, February is 1, etc.

`UTC()` will try to adapt invalid dates, so it's converting "June 31, 2010" into "July 1, 2010". Then, the extra 23:59:59 is making the first date larger.

Comment: (JavaScript inherits this highly questionable behaviour from Java.)