# Bug in Highcharts where negative numbers in data seem to cause bug with graph drawing

Tags: highcharts

I seem to have found a plotting bug see this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/MrSteve/Smu6r/

Source data:

```
<script src="http://gosargon.com/iconectiv/portWon.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

    chart: { },
    credits: {
            enabled: true
        },
    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        min: -20000,
        max: 20000,
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 60000,
            color: 'white'
        }, {
            from: -60000,
            to: 0,
            color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)'
        }]
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        buttonTheme: { // styles for the buttons
            fill: 'none',
            stroke: 'none',
                'stroke-width': 0,
            r: 8,
            style: {
                color: '#039',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            states: {
                hover: {},
                select: {
                    fill: '#039',
                    style: {
                        color: 'white'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        inputBoxBorderColor: 'gray',
        inputBoxWidth: 120,
        inputBoxHeight: 18,
        inputStyle: {
            color: '#039',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        labelStyle: {
            color: 'silver',
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Net',
        data: portsNetData
    }
            ]
});
```

});

Look at first few days of March and the hover shows all positive numbers by day (as does the json data) but the line takes a weird dip below zero similar to 1/27 -7661 value, but in March portion of X axis.  I see the same problem in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

The problem seems to be related to having negative data values.  When I remove them the problem goes away.

Suggestions and help welcome.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the javascript for errors you'll see this one:

http://www.highcharts.com/errors/15

> Highcharts expects data to be sorted
>
> This happens when you are trying to create a line series or a stock
>   chart where the data is not sorted in ascending X order. For
>   performance reasons, Highcharts does not sort the data, instead it is
>   required that the implementer pre-sorts the data.

This appears to be misleading because at first glance you data looks fine.

**BUT**, the with `Date.UTC` function, **the month is zero based** so some of your dates like

```
Date.UTC(2014,01,31)  // this is February the 31st!?!
```

don't make any sense and Date.UTC is [trying to make meaning out of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908587/javascript-date-utc-problem).

Comment: Curse you starting at Zero!!!  I have been programming many many years and I still make the same Stupid mistakes ;) - Many, many thanks Mark!